# Вернуть Id дубликата, если он существует mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Всем доброго вечера.
Есть 3 связанные таблицы, примерная схемка на фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть проста: У автора должно быть несколько книг.
Делаю запросы на INSERT в таблицы
К примеру был отправлен post запрос `authors.name = 'Gogol', books.title = 'VIY'`
добавляем транзакциями все эти данные в таблицы и в `books_authors` вставляем последние `id`.

НО, при следующем пост запросе `authors.name = 'Gogol', books.title = 'Death Souls'` - возникает ошибка, нельзя добавлять дубликат в таблицу `authors`.

Вопрос в следующем, как мне вернуть `id` того дубликата, что уже есть в таблице, для вставки в `books_authors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такую конструкцию

```
INSERT INTO authors (
  name
) VALUES (
  'Gogol'
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

Этот запрос вставит новую запись, если ее нет, и вернет ее id через `LAST_INSERT_ID()`/`mysql_insert_id()`. Если же такая запись есть, то выполнится строчка

```
id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

которая по сути не обновляет поля, но устанавливает значение `LAST_INSERT_ID`.

Для работы данной конструкции по полю `name` таблицы `authors` должен быть построен уникальный ключ

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: А можно полюбопытствовать, на какой уникальный индекс должно срабатывать `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: *и вернет ее id через LAST_INSERT_ID()/mysql_insert_id()* Вернёт, простите, куда?

Comment: @Akina На поле `name`

Comment: @Akina туда, откуда попросят

Comment: *На поле name* Я чёта не понял. В каментах к своему ответу у тебя уник есть, к моему - нет. Определись уже. И ещё - если ЕСТЬ уникальный индекс, ODKU не приведёт к каким-либо изменениям, и его смело можно заменить на IGNORE.

Comment: *туда, откуда попросят* В MySQL запрос на вставку ничего и никуда возвращать не умеет. Всё варится только внутри запроса. Исключение - UDV.

Comment: @Akina уникальный ключ на `authors`.`name`

Comment: Не было такого. Было только *возникает ошибка, нельзя добавлять дубликат в таблицу `authors`*. Про индекс - ни полслова. Где и по какой причине возникает ошибка, и какая ошибка - неизвестно.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO books (title)
VALUES ('title 1'), ('title 2'), ... ;

INSERT IGNORE INTO authors (name)
VALUES ('name 1'), ('name 2'), ... ;

INSERT IGNORE INTO books_authors (author_id, book_id)
SELECT authors.id, books.id
FROM authors, books
WHERE (authors.name, books.title) IN ( ('name 1', 'title 1'),
                                       ('name 2', 'title 2'),
                                       ... );
```

> как мне вернуть id того дубликата

А вот дубликаты надо удалить. ВСЕ.

Comment: Крайне благодарен. Сейчас проверю и отпишусь)

Comment: Итого: вначале вставляем авторов и книги, потом делаем запрос на получение идентификаторов вставленных записей, вместо того, чтобы получить их при вставке. Молимся, чтобы в базе не оказалось двух различных книг с одним названием. Гениально!

Comment: @AntonShchyrov *Молимся, чтобы в базе не оказалось двух различных книг с одним названием.* Что за бред, какие дубликаты? Изначально обеспечиваем, чтобы в таблице НЕ БЫЛО "двух различных книг с одним названием". Путём удаления дубликатов (с пересчётом ссылок) и последующим созданием уникального индекса. И только потом используем показанную технологию. Клиентская логика - не наш метод.

Comment: @Akina Не бред, а правда жизни. Два автора не могут выпустить две книги с идентичным названием?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Если говорить о жизни, а не о представленной модели, то у книги будет ISBN, дефолтно уникальный, и именно по нему будет отслеживаться дубликат. А название - так, сбоку. Но если имеется только название - да, нефиг дубликаты плодить, ибо нет иных данных, позволяющих различить записи.

Comment: @Akina Есть. Имя автора. И если книга вставляется одной транзакцией (о чем ТС написал) автор-книга-кросс, то абсолютно никакой проблемы в этом нет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov *Есть. Имя автора.* То есть одноимённые книги - бывают, нет проблем, а вот авторов - тёзок-однофамильцев - в природе не бывает? *книга вставляется одной транзакцией (о чем ТС написал)* Я лично понятия не имею, что имел в виду автор, набрав слово "транзакция". И сильно сомневаюсь, что имелось в виду `START TRANSACTION`.